# Unit Testing using C# with void function

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How can I do unit testing for the below class, as there is no any values in the code and there is no return and I should do the unit testing without modifying the code. What should I write in the test unit

Any Help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ORS
{
    public partial class DoctorAddEditMarks : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label2.Text = "" + Session["Username"];
        }

        protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/DoctorMainPage.aspx");
        }

        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];

                string coursecode = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
                string marktype = DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString();
                string fullmark = TextBox1.Text;
                string stid = row.Cells[0].Text;
                TextBox txtmark = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox2");
                string mark = txtmark.Text;

                String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                String query = "insert into Marks values (@St_ID, @CourseCode, @MarkType, @Mark, @FullMark)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseCode", coursecode);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@St_ID", stid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarkType", marktype);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mark", mark);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullMark", fullmark);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Marks are SuccessFully Saved');window.location ='DoctorAddEditMarks.aspx';", true);

        }
}
}
```

Comment: you have business logic/database access code in a GUI event handler. that does not lend itself well to unit testing. usually you would separate that into tiers, or at least make a testable (e.g. bool-returning) function out of the code in the click handler. or you are testing with a scriptable GUI simulator, and test for client-side ASP page results (coded UI test)

Comment: or write an additional test method that checks for the data which the click handler is supposed to insert.

Comment: I don't know how to do it for click handler

Comment: As @dlatikay mentioned, this code does not lend itself to unit testing.  You are accessing the database which is a big no no when unit testing since your data can change and break your test.  Tests should be independent of your data layer.  Instead your test should be using mock ups of the data that will stay static.  What you would want in this case is more of an integration test to test data retrieval/setting/updating.

Comment: @Abdmohd the code in the event (the void method) should be extracted to another function that does have a return type, preferable in another class all together.  The event method would then call this newly created method.

Comment: Without modifying the code?  Good luck.  You could use things like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) or other UI testing tools but you wont really be able to execute a true unit test - without a bit of refactoring.  We use [MVP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649571.aspx) for our aspx's - which allows separation of the logic from aspx.  The code sits in a different project/library which some (very few) tests are aimed at - presenters doing the ui logic.

Comment: @Abdmohd that code needs to be refactored to be more unit test friendly. read up on clean code with applying SOLID principles.

Comment: @Nkosi how can I refactor it I don't know anything about testing

Comment: @Abdmohd you do not need to know about testing to refactor the code. The first thing you have learned so far is that the current code you have there is not easily testable. In learning how to refactor the code you will learn how to make more test friendly which will help you learn more about testing.

Answer (score 0):

The first step to being able to test this would be to isolate the database code into its own class. It's pretty much impossible to unit test an .aspx page.

The test you write is technically not a unit test - it's an integration test. The difference is just that it's testing more than just your code. It's testing the combined functionality of your code and your database.

[This page](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/02/19/testing-data-access-and-stored-procedures.html) shows some simple ways to write those tests. It follows the typical arrange/act/assert pattern.

Arrange

- Make sure there’s no data in the table that will interfere with what
  I’m about to test
- Prepare my input

Act

- Call the method to insert my data

Assert

- Verify that the data is in the table just as I expect

Then I typically do a cleanup at the end to delete whatever test data I modified, which is often just repeating the first step.